# High RAM usage at startup, lowers immediately when virus scan is run

Tags: windows-7, memory, virus

After I turn on my computer, my RAM does this [image][image]

It hangs at 95+%, making my computer **very** slow.

---

[image]

is normal.

---

What's weird is that if I run a MSE virus scan, RAM frees up randomly. [image]

The vertical drops are when I run it. I only run it for 10 seconds, and then cancelled the scan for testing purposes.

---

There are no weird programs running or start-up programs.
[image][image]

---

Can someone figure out what is wrong, so the computer does Image 2, instead of Image 1?

Comment: If your memory usage is high something is using memory. Adjust which programs are capable of being ran during the startup procedure. Use a image host that allows you display the image within your post itself. I hate having to going to those image hosting websites myself.  465 memory usage is not high...during the startup procedure.  I see lots of programs you could disable to figure out which program is using a ton of memory.

Comment: You provide a screenshot where Chrome is using over 200MB worth of memory.

Comment: @Charlie - You only show some of your startup programs, and I see many, that I myself would disable.  Read this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: @David Schwartz, in image response to chmod, there is practically no RAM available. Computer slows down immensely.

Comment: @Ramhound, I show all programs that are checked.

Comment: @mrcharlie: If you have a *performance* problem, why didn't you say so? Your RAM usage is normal, so let's move on to other possible causes of your performance problem. Did you check your CPU temperature, for example? (You have plenty of RAM available, 2GB per figure 1. It's just also being used.)

Comment: @Charlie - Which means all of those programs will be ran at startup.  Read the article I linked to.  Figure out which service is using your memory.

Comment: I've seen this type of problem a few times. It's always been related to Windows caching (buffering) disk reads/writes of large files.

Comment: Please show the memory tab of the Resource monitor for image 2 instead of the overview tab when usage is > 90%.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain http://imgur.com/xzPkn

Comment: @mrcharlie - can you report back what services are running off the svchost.exe?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain http://i.imgur.com/iC99A.png

Comment: @mrcharlie: Notice that the commit charge doesn't go up? That's just SuperFetch loading things into memory in case they're needed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz alright, but my computer becomes extremely slow otherwise.. and why does running a virus scan stop the superfetch?

Comment: @mrcharlie: All the disk activity causes the RAM usage to change from prefetched data to cached data. The operating system can more easily discard cached data than prefetched data. Cached data can be immediately discarded by the OS. Prefetch data is less likely to be evicted because it's mapped by the SuperFetch service.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so all in all, this is normal behaviour? I mean I can't use the computer unless I run the scan.. I didn't do anything within the last few days to cause this behaviour.

Comment: @mrcharlie: The RAM usage is normal. The performance problem is not.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 will cache stuff in to ram, it is normal for your "free" RAM to be very low. Look at the "available" part. That is the amount of RAM you can use. This is pretty normal for Windows 7.

However, if your available RAM is low then look in the process tab and see which process is consuming the most RAM

You might want to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process  try perfmon or process explorer

Comment: Look at image 4.

Answer (score 0):

This looks perfectly normal. The memory is being used by the `SuperFetch` service because otherwise it would be wasted. If for some reason you'd prefer that memory not be used, remove it from the machine. It's not like if you use less RAM today you can use more tomorrow. Any RAM not used is opportunity to improve performance that is forever lost.

Comment: I understand what superfetch does. The problem is seen in image 4.

Comment: I don't see any problem. What exactly is the problem? If it's performance, let's troubleshoot that and stop worrying about normal RAM usage by SuperFetch.

Comment: Windows doesn't count cached data in the Physical Memory Usage History graph.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm wrong, but once physical memory hits 95+%, performance of the computer get s incredibly slow. I thought they were related.

Comment: @Louis: SuperFetch is distinct from the page cache. That's why it shows as part of SvcHost's memory.

Comment: @mrcharlie: So tell us some details about the performance problems and maybe we can figure out what the issue is. Does it perfectly correlate with free RAM getting low? Things are always fast before free RAM gets low? (There could be a connection, but it's not that you're "running out" of RAM.)

Comment: K I'll go step by step.

1. Turn on computer

2. Log in

3. Computer runs normally, but RAM usage increases linearly until it reaches 95% usage.

4. Computer is **really, really** slow, making everything lag.

5. Run MSE virus scan.

6. RAM decreases magically after a few seconds.

7. Computer runs normally.

Comment: @mrcharlie, I was actually pointing out to David Schwartz that the graph and SuperFetch are unrelated. There's nothing normal about image #4, and of course your computer will slow down when it starts using your disk drive for memory.

Comment: @mrcharlie If you don't do anything special, does it stay slow forever?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, it hangs at 96+% and the computer becomes unusable practically.